# error CS0534: [java class] does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

While Conversion from aar file to dll file in visual studio 2019 I got error like..

```
error CS0534: 'SettingDeviceInfo.GetMoreEngineTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'
error CS0534: 'SubscriptionActivity.GetSettingsTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'
error CS0534: 'SubscriptionAdapter.DeActivateTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'
```

I have try to install Xamarin.Build.AsyncTask NuGet package but I couldn't install because of it's not compatible with that framework. please help me to resolve this issue.
NOTE: I have install that dependencies NuGet Package but same error showing.

Comment: What is "Conversion from aar to dll"?
Please use defined terms otherwise no one will be able to help you.
Seem like you are trying to bind the Android artifact (aar or jar).

Xamarin.Build.AsyncTask is not for bindings. Simply adding any nuget with similar name will not solve your problems. That is voodoo programming and will introduce new issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this,change the **managedType** of the parameter to params Java.Lang.Object [] and change the **managedReturn** of the method to Java.Lang.Object. in **your Libarry** - **Transforms** - **Metadata.xml**

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='package_name']/class[@name='name']/method[@name='method_name' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='parameter_type']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">params Java.Lang.Object []</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='package_name']/class[@name='name']/method[@name='method_name' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='parameter_type']]" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

you could refer to the similar case:[Java binding](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104316/java-binding-class-does-not-implement-inherited-abstract-member)
and the [document](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#common-paths)